# grep from file based on the integer value

Tags: shell-scripting

How can I get details of the page that taking more than 10000 sec.

```
15:39:22,507NTP=/a/file/fname.pageTime=20559
15:40:10,811NTP=a/file/fname.pageTime=134
15:42:24,488NTP=a/file/fname.pageTime=10153
15:42:24,488NTP=a/file/fname.pageTime=10000
15:42:24,488NTP=a/file/fname.pageTime=101
```

I want to Out put as below as it is taking  more than 10000 sec:

```
15:39:22,507NTP=/a/file/fname.pageTime=20559
15:42:24,488NTP=a/file/fname.pageTime=10153
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said "grep", but here's an awk variation anyway. Try

```
awk -F 'pageTime=' '{ if ($2 > 10000) print $0 }' /path/to/your/logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If your datas are from a file named file : `egrep '=[0-9]{5}' file`
In this case you will have the 10000s too (as it have 5 digits)